# i18next-fetch-backend error while migrate to Angular 11

Tags: angular, i18next

[image]

Have issue after migrating to Angular 11 inside i18next-fetch-backend package index.d.ts. How to figure out this and how to fix it?

From index.d.ts
[image]

Comment: Yes, 4.0.0 version.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with a new version, 4.1.0

Comment: Does this also happen with i18next-http-backend?

Comment: Idk, we are using fetch.